# React - how to do jQuery style find() to find children of a DOM node?

Tags: reactjs

I've got a component that returns this:

```
return (
  <div className="audio-widget">
    <div
      className={this.props.className}
      onWheel={this.handleWheel}
      />
    {controls}
  </div>
)
```

I need to do the equivalent of:

```
handleWheel(event) {
  let $canvas = $('.audio-widget').find('canvas');
  [...]
}
```

The canvas is drawn programatically by a 3rd party script, so I can't just slap an ID on it (especially since this is a component and there are several per page).

Excuse the extreme n00b question, I'm brand new to React. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good use case for the `ref` prop. If you give a component a `ref` prop, e.g. `ref="foo"`, upon rendering that component will be available as e.g. `this.refs.foo`. Then you can get the rendered DOM node with `React.findDOMNode`.

```
render() {
  // ...
  return (
    <div ref="audioWidget" className="audio-widget">
      <div
        className={this.props.className}
        onWheel={this.handleWheel}
        />
      {controls}
    </div>
  );
}

handleWheel(event) {
  let canvas = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.audioWidget)
                 .querySelector('canvas');
  // ...
}
```

You can learn more about refs here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's a bad way to direct access 'canvas' with selector, the reason is as follows:

When you component changed, the React will do some diff works, then update your dom with a best way, that means, the node you get with selector may be changed to another node just for 'the best way'.

You can build a 'Child Component', and do something in the 'handleWheel' of the 'Parent Component', then communicate with the 'Child Component' through the 'props' for 'Child Component'